# Getting error while adding website for scan in Netsparker from HTTP request

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to add a website url to scan in Netsparker through java rest calls.

Authentication is done but getting this error:

```
Error- 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Frame-Options:
DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 08:48:51 GMT
Content-Length: 98
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: -1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Apigee Router
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Authentication request- 
PasswordAuthentication (AuthToken, "".toCharArray());
```

Recently they might have changed their API, So if, anyone have ever used this, and can provide a sample snippet, would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a code that just works without any dependencies.

Replace YOUR_API_TOKEN with your api token. 
If you want to create subscription-based website you should replace "Credit" with "Subscription".

```
package com.netsparkercloud;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String createWebsiteEndpoint = "https://www.netsparkercloud.com/api/1.0/websites/new";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(createWebsiteEndpoint);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic YOUR_API_TOKEN");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write("{\n" +
                    "  \"Name\": \"Java Test\",\n" +
                    "  \"RootUrl\": \"http://test.com\",\n" +
                    "  \"LicenseType\": \"Credit\"\n" +
                    "}");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream is;
            if (con.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                is = con.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                is = con.getInputStream();
            }

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            for ( int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read() )
                System.out.print((char)c);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ! Thanks Oguzhan Topcu. It really helped me.